# What credentials do I need to manage my own Drive with Google Drive API from a web app?

Tags: python, heroku, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am running a web app on heroku, and my goal is to copy files within my own drive using Google Drive API for python by sending commands to the app.

So far I have this code:

```
import os
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(json.loads(os.environ.get('CREDENTIALS')), scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)


http = creds.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http, cache_discovery=False)

folder = "12vQQwYK5bkg-6UKoNrXpsU1C1-fiYeTX"  # folder ID
file = "1EA25-BYr1AAUUDcstfVowDeGoygMGuxKxGxFYEdKTX0"  # file ID
title = "New_file_id"

service.files().copy(fileId=file,
                           body={"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink",
                                 "id": folder}], 'title': title}).execute()
```

But it gets stuck on executing POST request forever. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Drive API v3, please use `name` to give the filename instead of `title`. And please put `kind` to the outside of `parents`. So how about the following modification for `body`?

#### From :

```
{
    "parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": folder}],
    'title': title
}
```

#### To :

```
{
    "parents": [folder],
    "name": title,
    "kind": "drive#fileLink"
}
```

#### Reference :

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/copy)

If this didn't lead to the solution, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it raises `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1EA25-BYr1AAUUDcstfVowDeGoygMGuxKxGxFYEdKTX0/copy?alt=json returned "File not found: 12vQQwYK5bkg-6UKoNrXpsU1C1-fiYeTX.">` and freezes again if I omit `parents` parameter. Do you think it may be caused by insufficient permissions?

Comment: @Vasily I'm sorry for the inconvenience. The error says ``File not found``. If the authorization error occurs, the authorization error will occur before the files are searched. So can you confirm the file ID again? And can you also try other file ID? And also for example, how about removing ``"kind": "drive#fileLink"`` from the body?

Comment: @Tanaikе sure, file id is exactly the right one, as well as folder id. When I remove  `"kind": "drive#fileLink"` it gets stuck on POST again (`googleapiclient.discovery - INFO - URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1EA25-BYr1AAUUDcstfVowDeGoygMGuxKxGxFYEdKTX0/copy?alt=json`)

Comment: @Vasily I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Did you get the error messages? And, for example, can you get the response from a variable like ``res = service.files().copy()``?

Comment: @Tanaikе, you already helped a lot, thank you! When I tried your last suggestion, I got: `raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
2018-01-27T00:59:51.148216+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Missing required parameter "fileId"`. By the way, do you think the problem may be caused with me using non-default library? (i.e. `client = gspread.authorize(creds)`)

Comment: @Vasily It seems that ``client = gspread.authorize(creds)`` is not used in your snippet of your question. For example, when ``res = service.files().list().execute()``, which doesn't use parameters, instead of ``service.files().copy()`` is used, if file list can be retrieved, it is found that the authorization is correct. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaikе, sorry, it freezes again, but now with GET :) (`URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json`)

Comment: @Vasily I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can you show us the response of ``res``?

Comment: sure: it returns this when I wrap the function in print `{'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '13hOxehZI7um0z9EugGQtXU4Ph2FLEqrWNAJEG9-UF2w', 'name': 'Copy of test_table_template', 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}. But it still freezes in process and no new files are created after =\

Comment: @Vasily From your latest comments, it is found that the script retrieve file list. I cannot understand about "no new files are created after =\ –". I had thought that you ran ``res = service.files().list().execute()``. That doesn't create files. I'm confusing about this. Can I ask you about this situation?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to specify that response I posted was from copy() method. As for list() it returns json with a list of files, and then freezes

Comment: @Vasily Can you show us your current script? Because in my environment, your script in your question with my modification works fine, I would like to confirm about your current script. If you can do, please update or add it on your question. I'm sorry for taking your time because of my incomplete answer.

Comment: I am ready to post it, but I realized the problem may be connected to other thing: 1) first, .copy() throws `<HttpError 404 ... "File not found: 12vQQwYK5bkg-6UKoNrXpsU1C1-fiYeTX.">` (although the dot in the end is not present in code - rather it seems that service account has no permissions to access the folder) 2) Everything works fine without `"parents": [folder]` part, but when I try to open the returned file id I see: "You need permission, request access..." thing.   So I think my service account doesen't have permissions to manage files on my drive. But don't know how to fix it either =\

Comment: @Vasily Thank you for your additional information. From your comments, it is found that the call of API works and your issue is one step closer to the solution. About the permission of folder, I would like to confirm 2 things. 1. Are the folder or drive you want to use yours or your drive? 2. In order to confirm the issue, as a sample, will you use access token for this situation?

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for all your recommendations - it all works now, the last issue was with permissions - finally I got a refresh token to access my drive with oauthplayground, embedded it in credentials and it all works now!

Comment: @Vasily Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your problem was solved.